# Regular Expressions in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Do the Cognito Forms support *Regular Expressions* to validate fields?

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) can support custom regular expressions in a [Text field](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/44/building-forms/form-field-reference/textbox-field). We also have some default regular expressions set up that can be selected. In Cognito Forms this is called Format Validation, and this allows you to validate (and potentially reformat) user input. For example: a Textbox field with format validation set to Numeric will require users to enter only numbers. You can choose from a variety of standard formats, or specify your own custom format.